# What is this oddly shaped hinged device with indentations?

Tags: equipment, utensils

[image] [image]

What is this device? It's about 8cm long when closed, and has little indentations on the top piece and raised lines on the bottom. Possibly it could be used to crush garlic etc.?

Comment: You sure can use it for the mythical *allium sativum giganteum enormum*! One clove feeds 4 ;-).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It's a lemon/lime wedge juice squeezer.
Only place I've ever really seen them used is in British Indian restaurants.

Pop a wedge in the gap, squeeze the handles, juice can be poured with reasonable accuracy from any of the fluted edges. No messy fingers.

[image]

Image from [Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/KitchenCraft-Stainless-Steel-Lemon-Squeezers/dp/B0001IX2UG)

Comment: Correct. Also seen in middle-class German restaurants (-> lemon juice on Viennese schnitzel) or cafes (-> lemon for your tea), especially back in the 1960s and later. Haven’t seen them in years.

Comment: Well actual used in minimum one German restaurant at the Baltic Sea for the fish :)

Comment: looks cool, but ultimately is just a one trick tool nobody really needs adding clutter.

Comment: I want one! Very widely available on the web.

Comment: @dandavis Depends on how many tools you actually have, and if this particular tool is something you would use often.

Comment: Once a week, maybe. It's pretty small. I have a potato ricer that is used maybe once a month.